# No source image provided with `FROM`dockerfile-utils(20)

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to create a node server using Docker but I am getting and error on 'FROM' instruction and I have no clue what is going on, never seen that before. Does anyone knows how to solve it?

```
No source image provided with `FROM`dockerfile-utils(20)
Unknown instruction: FROM:dockerfile-utils(38)
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM: node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /app/backend

COPY package.json /app/backend

RUN npm install

COPY . /app/backend/

EXPOSE 3001

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

**docker-compose**

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  backend:
    build: ./
    container_name: node_container
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    restart: always
    working_dir: /app/backend
    volumes:
      - ./:/app/backend
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    ports:
      - 3001:3001

  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0.26
    container_name: mysqldb_container
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the colon from the `FROM` command

```
FROM node:16-alpine
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dockerfile's FROM shouldn't contain :

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /app/backend

COPY package.json /app/backend

RUN npm install

COPY . /app/backend/

EXPOSE 3001

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

Remove the ":" from the FROM